# What is the expected return of the clone() method in PHP?

Tags: php

I am building a small framework, and I'm trying to implement a clone() method in some of my objects. The goal of this method is to create a fresh copy of a given record, making it easier to the user to create a new record based in another one.

It seemed to me a perfect scenario to use the clone() and __clone() PHP methods. But what exactly should be returned by calling clone()? When I create a clone, semms like the cloned object is the same as the original, even though I have changed some properties inside the __clone magic method.

Here is what I have done unitl now:
My application uses ascincronous communication, so there is a Service class, called by the API; This Service class creates a new  instance of my Record class, and creates a clone. Inside this Record class, there is a implementation of the __clone magic method, to make some changes in the data, and save the new record.

the cloneRecord method inside Service Class:

```
public function cloneRecord($original_id) {
    $originalObject = new Record($original_id);
    $originalObject->load(); //access the database and retrieve the property values for this record
    $cloned = clone $originalObject;
    return $cloned->id; // here is the problem! See explanation below
}
```

the __clone method inside Record Class:

```
public function __clone() {
    $cloned = new Record();

    //id and code will be generated automatically in the save() method:
    $cloned->id = NULL;
    $cloned->code = NULL;

    //these other properties will be cloned:
    $cloned->name = $this->name;
    $cloned->startDate = $this->startDate;
    $cloned->dueDate = $this->dueDate;

    $cloned->save();
}
```

Until this point, everything seems to work properly. The new Record is saved into the database, a new id and a new code is generated for this new Record.

How I call the method:

```
$service = new Service();
$newRecordId = $service->cloneRecord(200);
```

Here something strange happens!
What I expect to get from the line above is the id of the new Record (perhaps, 201). Instead, I receive the same original id (200).

Is this is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Shouldn't you return something in your `__clone` override?

Comment: @jraede Yes, I tried with `return $cloned`, but the behaviour was the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php#object.clone) of `__clone()`. It says:

> Once the cloning is complete, if a __clone() method is defined, then the newly created object's __clone() method will be called, to allow any necessary properties that need to be changed.

This means `__clone()` will run in the scope of the newly created object.

---

Your `__clone()` method should look like this:

```
public function __clone() {

    //id and code will be generated automatically in the save() method:
    $this->id = NULL;
    $this->code = NULL;

    // I would not put it here. It should happen explicitly (imo)
    // But this design decision is up to you.
    $this->save(); 
}
```

Comment: The `save()` probably generates the new `id` and populates it. Having `id` as `null` up to then seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Except, of course, that you don't need to include the `$this->name = $this->name`, etc.  Might be better commented out?

Comment: Or `$this->name = clone $this->name` if you want deep copies, assuming the values are not scalars.

Comment: @RafaelHenrique `Maybe $this inside the __clone() reffers to the cloned object`. Yes, the documentation states this. Yeah, it is better to call save in the Service class. This because normally the usage of `clone $obj;` does not lead to such side effects. So there might be other libraries you are using (or might use in the future) and these might call clone - for whatever reasons - because they don't expect these side effects.

Comment: @hek2mgl Using your implementation of __clone() worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: @RafaelHenrique Ok. Happy cloning! ;)